# Recibir variables post y escribirlas en Html

Tags: php, android, http, post, slim

estoy recibiendo datos por post desde un sistema android, al responder con `echo`, estos datos llegan a android. Ahora quiero usar estos datos para usarlos en una página html, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo? Por cierto uso el framework Slim.

```
 <?php
       require 'Slim/Slim.php';
       \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

       $sistema = new \Slim\Slim();
       $sistema->get('/', function() {
           echo("Hola mundo!");
       });
       $sistema->post('/gps', function() {
          $longitud = $_POST['long'];
          $latitud = $_POST['lat'];
          echo("Posición: " . $longitud . " " . $latitud);
      });
      $sistema->run();
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final no encontré mejor solución que pasar mis datos a una base de datos. Con la base de datos lista, es fácil poder usar los datos en cualquier ruta de mi página html.

Supongo que esto es lo que dictan las buenas prácticas.

Comment: Quizás no estoy comprendiendo bien el problema, pero no le encuentro sentido a esta respuesta (ni a la referencia de las buenas prácticas)

Comment: Hola. Como puse en la pregunta envío datos a un servidor desde Android, y usaba una estructura tipo Api Rest, al enviar los datos por post, cuando respondía los datos eran obviamente devueltos a Android. Entonces lo que yo quería era usar esos datos pero no en Android si no en el mismo servidor y presentarlos en la web. Pero no tenía claro como pasar los datos a otra función o clase. Bueno encontré que por defecto para eso podemos usar una base de datos, y leer la data desde cualquier parte de nuestro servidor web.

Answer (score 2):

Deberías revisar la Arquitectura Rest, en terminos generales tendrás que crear un api, mediante la cual expondrás tus recursos con los cuales podrás interactuar mediante los verbos http

- get(pedir datos)
- post(enviar datos)
- put(actualizar datos)
- delete(eliminar datos)

Asi desde cualquier dispositivo como un celular, una tarjeta arduino, u otro dispositivo que se pueda comunicar mediante http, podrás enviar datos a través una petición post, y mediante una peticion get obtener los datos de cualquier recurso, y asi renderizarlo en un navegador(para hacer esto, puedes usar ajax, o algun frammework como angular).

Como puedes ver con REST logras muchos beneficios, como interacción entre diferentes dispositivos, ademas de que obtendrás escalabilidad, y muchos beneficios mas,

Creo que deberias documentarte un poco mas acerca de REST para tener una mejor idea, por cierto usar slim ya es un acierto porque es un microframework orientado a APi's

Answer (score 1):

Deberías usar un motor de plantillas Slim Ofrece [Twig en su web oficial](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html)